# Trouble with RoboBrowser in Python 3.6

Tags: python

This is probably very simple to anyone experienced, but I am a beginner and spent hours trying to open a website using RoboBrowser. I have Python 3.6 installed and believe I successfully installed the package through the command prompt. When I execute the below code using Geany, nothing happens besides a box that pops up saying hit any key to continue. The next step is to login, but no point worrying about that until I can actually get the website to open.

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open('https://login.salesforce.com/')
```

Comment: Hi! I don't know anything about robobrowser, but shouldn't it read `browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)`? Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Sorry. I originally had that, but kept switching it in hopes of it working. Switched it back to RoboBrowser and still nothing. I just get (program exited with code: 0) <br> Press any key to continue. . . I'm not sure if Python 3.6 is compatible with it, but the documentation states:                                                                                        Requirements
------------

- Python >= 2.6 or >= 3.3

Answer (score 0):

To install RoboBrowser, `pip install robobrowser` in an administrative shell should be sufficient.

The Code seems OK, you could try to start it with a shell.
Just cd into the directory of the Python source-file and execute it via `py <filename.py>`, `python <filename.py>` or `python3 <filename>.py` (depending on your environment-variables).

The "hit any key to continue" probably just tells you, that the program finished successfully. You are not printing anything on the screen.

Comment: Correct. I used pip install as mentioned above. I believe it was successful since I didn't receive any kickback. I tried running the file, which I titled Website.py, in the command prompt, but still got the same result. I used C:\Users\kplass\Desktop\python_work>python Website.py. A browser is supposed to open and show the website, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your code opens the website, and the received information (page) is in the `browser` object. You can proceed to use it further (e.g. for logging in) with calls like `browser.get_form(...)`, as in the [examples](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser).

Comment: I am just trying to get the code to open a viewable browser with the specified website for now. Goal is to eventually do what you are saying. I can get to that point using standard library, but want to do it with robobrowser. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Kevin from robobrowser's [documentation](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [source](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/tree/master/robobrowser), it doesn't provide that functionality. However, there is a [module `webbrowser` in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html).

Comment: So robobrowser accesses the website in the background so you don't actually see it?

Comment: > "robobrowser accesses the website in the background so you don't actually see it" - yes, that's what it is for. Additionally, robobrowser is a wrapper on top of `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`, so there isn't even a browser, and, therefore, for example, no javascript support (you'd need `phantomjs` for that).

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, really helpful. I am very new to this.